# Android - Unable to use libraries

Tags: android

My app crashes when I try to use libraries (like Google Analytics or others).

I've searched on Google and found some help but it still doesn't work...

My lib folder is called "libs", I've got jar in the build path...

Have you got any ideas?

The error is :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker

EDIT : 
Here my conf :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Does this only happen with Google libraries? If so, are you using the Google API version of the SDK you want to use?

Comment: What editor are you using? I'll post an answer for Eclipse.

Comment: Yes I'm using Eclipse. Seiyria, it's happen with all my libraries...

Comment: Verify that your Android MANIFEST (xml) has a reference to the library

Comment: Where in the Android Manifest does he need to add references, @ccheneson? As far as mine go, they don't have any and they're working fine.

Comment: there should be a like starting with <uses-library . See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html

Comment: Right you are. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Eclipse`, try this

1. Select your Project with the Mouse
2. `Right click->Properties`
3. Select `Android`
4. Verify that you've selected the "`Google APIs`" version that you need for your project
5. At the bottom, your `Libraries` should also appear. If they don't
6. Click the `Add` button. Add the missing libraries. Careful, though, your libraries need to use compatible APIs to your main project.

Comment: post an image with your Eclipse configuration. That might help. Especially since the "libs" directory doesn't apply to Android projects, if I recall it correctly. In the Package Explorer there should be a reference to the Google APIS, below that the EasyTracker jar should appear as well.

Comment: Yeah, I see you've got the references in properties. However, I'm still puzzled about your lib folder. Above that directory you see both the Google APIs and Android Dependencies folders. In them is where your missing Google Libraries should actually appear. Check whether they're there as well.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand... Where do you want I check that ? thanks.

Comment: Click the arrow next to Google APIs in the project whose image you took

Comment: There are android.jar, effects.jar, usb.jar, maps.jar. I don't think the problem is here, because others libraries like jackson, restrung and others doesn't work...

Comment: Before I delete my Eclipse by error, I've no problems... Since I've downloaded it again, this problem is appeared

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33208/discussion-between-digcamara-and-florian-mac-langlade)